# Security patch 11219 risk error for Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

Security patch 11219 risk Error for Magento 1.9.2.4

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 version

in the Security patch error(magereport.com)

[image]

But in the Magento Security patch not have this version (https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

[image]

How to I use Security patch for this ?

Comment: Magento has not released the Security patch 11219 for Magento versions below 1.9.3.0 yet.

Comment: yes but magereport.com is show the error what I do? - pay fast not working for this issues

Comment: New versions for <1.9.3 should be released soon...
https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/1185089895565529089